# Linux web browser as screensaver

Tags: centos, screensaver

I would like to be able to display my Nagios dashboard on our group computer when the screen is locked. Ideally we could just load Firefox or Opera into kiosk mode with a screen locker but after two days of struggling I have not been able to get this too work. We are using CentOS 6.3 with Gnome.

How do I get a screensaver to show a web page or rotate over a list of web pages.

Thank you.